# How to increase query efficiency for a large volume of data in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-performance

I have a PostgreSQL database with *1.2 billions rows*, attempted to make an application that queries rows a million at a time, with an option to query larger intervals. 
At first I was just querying a database of a *million to 10 million* with ease; 
Now that I'm querying a large database with an `OFFSET` the `ResultSet` takes a long time to generate.

```
   // ...
   stmt.setFetchSize(100000);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT mmsi, report_timestamp, position_geom, ST_X(position_geom) AS Long, "
                        + "ST_Y(position_geom) AS Lat FROM reports4 WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL ORDER by report_timestamp ASC LIMIT "
                        + limit + " OFFSET " + set);
```

So the `ORDER BY`is probably killing my execution time, but having the information ordered makes things easier later on. Is there a more efficient way to query the rows in intervals ?

Comment: What indices do you have at your table?

Comment: If your table was indexed on `report_timestamp`, this would be almost a no-op. I think there are also partial indices which can match your `where` clause precisely.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT mmsi, report_timestamp, position_geom, ST_X(position_geom) AS Long, "
                        + "ST_Y(position_geom) AS Lat
FROM reports4
WHERE position_geom IS NOT NULL
ORDER by report_timestamp ASC;
```

You should be able to use an index on an expression:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_reports4_position_ts ON reports4((position_geom IS NOT NULL), report_timestamp)
```

This index should be used directly for the query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff , I was unaware of INDEX, I'll do some reading :)

Comment: This partitions the index into "is null" and "is not null" cases; better performance will probably be achieved with a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html).

Comment: @guy_sensei: wow, 1.2 **billion** rows and you never had the need to create an index? You must have some extremely powerful hardware...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a partial index that is built over a subset of your database.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_reports4 ON reports4(position_geom, report_timestamp) where position_geom IS NOT NULL;
```

This would increase the performance considerably as you are just indexing a part of the database that is required.